I am having TypeScript Compilation Issues in my Node.js Project
I am using Knex.js as the ORM for my node.js typescript microservice project. The Issue is my typescript seems to be complaining about parameters not having types assigned to them. This started to happen when i was trying to i find a way to allow my dao folders to have access to an instance of the db through my 'mysql.loader.ts' connection file for the dao functions to work
for reference my directory structure is like this
[project structure](https://i.sstatic.net/JffrAUO2.jpg)

whenever i try to start the project "npm run start" i get this error:
C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\lendsqr_test\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:859
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
       ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
utils/tokenizer.ts:2:32 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

2 var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
                             ~~~~
utils/tokenizer.ts:2:67 - error TS7006: Parameter 'mod' implicitly has an 'any' type.

2 var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
                                                                ~~~
utils/tokenizer.ts:7:19 - error TS7006: Parameter 'email' implicitly has an 'any' type.

7 module.exports = (email, UserId) => {
                ~~~~~
utils/tokenizer.ts:7:26 - error TS7006: Parameter 'UserId' implicitly has an 'any' type.

7 module.exports = (email, UserId) => {
                       ~~~~~~

at createTSError (C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\lendsqr_test\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:859:12)
at reportTSError (C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\lendsqr_test\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:863:19)
at getOutput (C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\lendsqr_test\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1077:36)
at Object.compile (C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\lendsqr_test\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1433:41)
at Module.m._compile (C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\lendsqr_test\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1617:30)
at Module.m._compile (C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\lendsqr_test\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at require.extensions.<computed> (C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\lendsqr_test\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\xampp\htdocs\htdocs\lendsqr_test\node_modules\ts-       
node\src\index.ts:1621:12)       
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32) {
diagnosticCodes: [ 2532, 7006, 7006, 7006 ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

for reference this is the file it is supponsingly complaining about:
import createToken from "./jwt_helper";

module.exports = (email: string, UserId: string) => {
const time = UserId + "-" + Date.now();
const token = createToken(email, UserId, time);

return {
    token,
  };
};`

some of the lines that are being complained about in the error are basically empty space lines
NOTE: Also i tried compiling my project and i realised that the complied version is doesnt seem to be from my current code version but from an older version (to verify this i changed afew things around in some files and they did not reflect in the complied version..but some other things show up..comments for example)..like it is selectively updating..this happens with the code it complains about
